# Running node script on startup with cron

Tags: boot, node.js

I know this has been as been asked before. I followed lots of tuts how to do this and I want to do it with cron.

First problem is sudo vs regular user. I write in nodeJS, while I managed to have both users on the same up-to-date node version I'd prefer not to use sudo.

This is what I tried:

1. `which node` outputs `/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v7.5.0/bin/node`
2. `crontab -e` and use nano
3. I add `@reboot /home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v7.5.0/bin/node /home/pi/projects/pi-bootup/server.js`, exit and save.
4. I insert `/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v7.5.0/bin/node /home/pi/projects/pi-bootup/server.js` to test if the command works (it does).
5. I check with `ps -e|grep node` for running node tasks (yup, they're there)
6. `sudo reboot`.
7. after reboot, I check for running node tasks with `ps -e|grep node`. None started.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I also added `@reboot echo "hi" > /home/pi/reboot.txt 2>&1` and the file is created after reboot. So the reboot jobs run, just the node task isn't running... or am I verifying this the wrong way?

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm new to Raspberry and Linux, (kinda new to node too).

Comment: Is using cron a firm requirement? If you just want to start a node server on boot using systemd offers a lot more flexibility in terms of restarting, which user is running the process, environment variables and so on?

Comment: @tobyd not really a requirement. It seemed easier though. I'll switch if this isn't possible using cron but right now I'd like to know why this isn't working.

Comment: you could try adding an `&` to the end of your script definition to background it. I'm not entrely sure cron would be happy running a foreground task on boot? That would be my only suggestion. The `echo hi` bit would be fast and not cause problems but you might find the OS kills off the node process early on for causing a delay.

Comment: made it work with this:
http://weworkweplay.com/play/raspberry-pi-nodejs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @tobyd said: it was better to not use cron. No idea why. I made it work using this tutorial:
http://weworkweplay.com/play/raspberry-pi-nodejs/

Comment: For a marginally more flexible solution you could use either supervisor (http://supervisord.org/running.html) or systemd (https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) to handle automatic restarts for you. rc.local IRC doesn't handle this scenario and node apps can be problematic on failure. Glad its sorted though.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 1):

If you can successfully run your `node` command from your interactive shell (default `bash` on RPi OS), then you can also run it in `cron` under `@reboot`. When a *program* runs from the command line/interactive shell, but fails to run under `cron` with the `@reboot` facility, this is usually because `crond` has started, but a service required by the *program* has not yet been started by [`init`](https://cotraco.eu/linux/what-is-init-system-in-linux.html) - which for RPi OS is handled by `systemd`.

Typically, the simple solution is to instruct `cron` to `sleep` for a short time before trying to execute the *program*:

```
@reboot /bin/sleep 30; /home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v7.5.0/bin/node /home/pi/projects/pi-bootup/server.js
```

At boot time, `cron` will run `sleep` for 30 seconds, and then will run `node`. Nothing magic about 30 seconds - feel free to try other (larger or smaller) values as required.